# Hibernate , Criteria.list() returns more row of what i expect

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a problem with a project with spring and hibernate :

In my database(mysql) i have these tables :

```
table Operator{
     idOperator int(12) primary key auto_increment,
     name varchar(20),
     surname varchar(20),
     username varchar(20),
     password varchar(20),
     type varchar(2)
     } engin=InnoDB;

 table Customer{
      idCustomer int primary key,
      name varchar(20),
      surname varchar(20),
      lastOrder date,
 } engine = InnoDB;
```

and a many to many relationship between the two previous tables :

```
table portfolio{
    idOperator int,
    idCustomer int,
    foreign key(idOperator) references Operator(idOperator)on update cascade on delete cascade
    foreign key(idCustomer) references Customer(idCustomer) on update cascade on delete cascade
}engine = InnoDB;
```

In my Entity class for Operator i mapped the table in this way :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "idOperator")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "portfolio", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOperator")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCustomer")
})
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

when i ask the list of the operators with this code :

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Operator.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type","ad"));
    return criteria.list();
```

the result include each operator a number of time equal at the number of times in which the operator partecipates in the relationship 'portfolio'.

Someone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: try using Projections.distinct on your criteria

Answer (score 0):

try like below:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Operator.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("type","ad"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")))
    return criteria.list();
```

Comment: I tried your hints ,but i get the following error : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type java.lang.Integer

Comment: do you have getter and setter for id in your entity?

Comment: Yes, for now i solved adding this line :  criteria.setResultTrasformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);